# Samba error: reply_trans: invalid trans parameters

Tags: 18.04, samba

I'm trying to enable folder sharing through samba on my ubuntu 18.04 server;

What I already did:

1. Edit the /etc/samba/smb.conf as in follow

> ```
> [global]
> workgroup = WORKGROUP
> interfaces = lo eth0
> server role = standalone server
> server string = Samba Server %v
> security = user
> map to guest = bad user
> name resolve order = bcast host
> dns proxy = no
> bind interfaces only = yes
> log file = /var/log/samba/smb.log
> max log size = 10000
>
> [Public]
>    path = /samba/share
>    writable = yes
>    guest ok = yes
>    guest only = yes
>    read only = no
>    create mode = 0777
>    directory mode = 0777
>    force user = nobody
> ```

2. Run testparm with this result

> ```
> Load smb config files from /etc/samba/smb.conf rlimit_max: increasing
> rlimit_max (1024) to minimum Windows limit (16384) Processing section
> "[Public]" Loaded services file OK. Server role: ROLE_STANDALONE
>
> Press enter to see a dump of your service definitions
>
> # Global parameters [global]
>     bind interfaces only = Yes
>     dns proxy = No
>     interfaces = lo eth0
>     log file = /var/log/samba/smb.log
>     map to guest = Bad User
>     max log size = 10000
>     name resolve order = bcast host
>     security = USER
>     server role = standalone server
>     server string = Samba Server %v
>     idmap config * : backend = tdb
>
>
> [Public]
>     create mask = 0777
>     directory mask = 0777
>     force user = nobody
>     guest ok = Yes
>     guest only = Yes
>     path = /samba/share
>     read only = No
> ```

3. Restart smbd.service
4. Trying to log on through windows ; windows cannot access \SERVERNAME\...
5. See errors log

> ```
> [2019/06/23 21:05:54.565424,  0]
> ../lib/util/become_daemon.c:124(daemon_ready)   STATUS=daemon 'smbd'
> finished starting up and ready to serve connections [2019/06/23
> 21:06:34.482176,  0] ../source3/smbd/ipc.c:843(reply_trans)  
> reply_trans: invalid trans parameters
> ```

I have been on this for around 5 days, does someone have any clues what's going on? how to fix this? I just need one public share and another one for restricted access.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the server via the IP address of the machine?

Comment: yes, i am. in fact, I connect to the ssh server via ip address. firewall ufw disabled

Comment: Im at church right now, but there is a small python utility which propagates names through SMB. I will look it up when I get home, and it works pretty well. I run it has a service, which took just a little setup

Answer (score 0):

> bind interfaces only = Yes
>
> interfaces = lo eth0

You are telling samba to use only certain interfaces but the one you specified ( eth0 ) doesn't exist in Ubuntu 18.04. It's a different form.

Unless you have a reason for specifying anything and would rather just let samba figure this out on its own I would remove those two lines from smb.conf and restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

If you do want to specify a certain interface use this command to find its real name:

```
nmcli device show | grep DEVICE
```

Answer (score 0):

Windows now uses WSD (web services discovery?) which is not included in the various Samba's that are available as of Ubuntu 19.04.

There is a project at github which implements WSD, written in Python. It can be found at https://github.com/christgau/wsdd or directly downloaded at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/christgau/wsdd/master/src/wsdd.py

Part of the trick to using this is that you will need to enable a couple of ports through your firewall:

Ports 5357/tcp and 3702/udp need to be open for wsdd to run.

wsdd can be run from the command line, or you could create a systemd service to run it.

This is an active (maybe) area of Samba development, and some information about it can be found at https://www.ixsystems.com/community/resources/how-to-kill-off-smb1-netbios-wins-and-still-have-windows-network-neighbourhood-better-than-ever.106/ and is currently available in the Arch user repository, and apparently a few other distros as well. It is also mentioned in AskUbuntu at [make samba share visible in Windows "Network"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/661611/make-samba-share-visible-in-windows-network)

**Starting as a service**

I created a systemd service unit file for wsdd as `/lib/systemd/system/wsdd.service`  The contents are

```
[Unit]
Description=WSDD Network Service
BindsTo=smbd.service
After=smbd.service

[Service]
Type=simple
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/usr/bin/wsdd
#ExecReload=/user/bin/wsdd

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then I moved `wsdd.py` to `/usr/bin/wsdd`, and modified its permissions to 555 (read and execute).

Finally, `sudo systemctl enable wsdd.service` and a reboot - and my Ubuntu system is now visible to my Win10 computers.